# What is the relationship between Alice and McFeen in "The Vanderlark"?

Tags: short-stories, margaret-st-clair

Margaret St. Clair's short story ["The Vanderlark"](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/64014/64014-h/64014-h.htm) is set on a spaceship in deep space with a crew of two, Alice and McFeen (or Mac). The interaction between the two is odd: McFeen slaps Alice near the beginning of the story, later they get drunk together and swap stories, and she often flatters him on his cleverness. What exactly is the relationship between them? Are they comrades and travelling companions? Lovers? Is he her boss?

Comment: In the [accompanying artwork](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/64014/64014-h/images/illus.jpg), neither character is wearing a wedding ring

Comment: "*And then, relenting (after all, he and Alice had been through a lot together),"* - That seems to be all that you get from the text.